# Laravel 4 - Route group prefix suddenly became fussy

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I really don't know what has happened here. Essentially I have a group of routes which are prefixed with admin like so:

```
<?php

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route model binding
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::model('role', 'Role');

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Admin Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function() {

        # User Management
        Route::get('users/{user}/show', 'AdminUsersController@getShow')
            ->where('user', '[0-9]+');
        Route::get('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@getEdit')
            ->where('user', '[0-9]+');
        Route::post('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@postEdit')
            ->where('user', '[0-9]+');
        Route::get('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@getDelete')
            ->where('user', '[0-9]+');
        Route::post('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@postDelete')
            ->where('user', '[0-9]+');
        Route::controller('users', 'AdminUsersController');

        # User Role Management
        Route::get('roles/{role}/show', 'AdminRolesController@getShow')
            ->where('role', '[0-9]+');
        Route::get('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@getEdit')
            ->where('role', '[0-9]+');
        Route::post('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@postEdit')
            ->where('role', '[0-9]+');
        Route::get('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@getDelete')
            ->where('role', '[0-9]+');
        Route::post('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@postDelete')
            ->where('role', '[0-9]+');
        Route::controller('roles', 'AdminRolesController');

        # Admin Dashboard
        Route::controller('/', 'AdminDashboardController');
    });


/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Frontend Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
// User reset routes
Route::get('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@getReset')
    ->where('token', '[0-9a-z]+');
// User password reset
Route::post('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@postReset')
    ->where('token', '[0-9a-z]+');
//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/{user}/edit', 'UserController@postEdit')
    ->where('user', '[0-9]+');

//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@postLogin');

# User RESTful Routes (Login, Logout, Register, etc)
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');

//:: Application Routes ::
# Filter for detect language
Route::when('contact-us', 'detectLang');

# Contact Us Static Page
Route::get('contact-us', function() {
        // Return about us page
        return View::make('site/contact-us');
    });

# Index Page - Last route, no matches
//Route::get('/', array('before' => 'detectLang', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getIndex'));
Route::get('{par1}', function($par1) {
        return $par1;
    });
Route::get('{par1}/{par2}', function($par1, $par2) {
        return $par1 . '-' . $par2;
    });
Route::get('/', function() {
        return 'route not found';
    });

//filters.php

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());
        return Redirect::to('user/login/');
    }
});
```

This used to work fine but has suddenly decided it doesn't like the word admin as a prefix, so for example when visiting and of the routes admin/x or admin/x/y/z I get the route not found message. However for some reason if I change this prefix to anything else, e.g sadmin my routes work as before. Still stranger is the fact that if I try something like mysite.com/var1/var2, my parameter return route returns var1 and var2. but if I do admin/var1, I get the route not found message.

Any ideas what might have changed here.... I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything in the routes file... I was working on the conrollers at the time. Unfortunately Ctrl+Z didn't save me and it's been a while since I pushed the changes.

Comment: did you make a controller called admin?

Comment: I have always had an Admin Controller - AdminRolesController and AdminUsersController both extend it. This was the case before it broke so I'm not sure it's related - but I am open to any suggestions at this point

Comment: is that your full route file?

Comment: and what is your 'auth' filter doing? maybe the problem is there?

Comment: This was not my full routes file - I have updated with full content

Comment: I have also added my auth filter, but again nothing has changed in the filters or routes, the changes being made at the time were to the controller but all that changed was replacing static calls to classes for instantiated object calls. Do you want me to post one or both of the controllers - roles and users aren't working. I have tried commenting out everything in the controller except a die statement on the index method and even this isn't being reached!!

Comment: maybe try removing all the excess routes and work backwards - rebuilt the routes one by one?

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have jsut worked this out thanks to your suggestions... comes done to user error (user=me) I think I need to put some restrictions on editing the admin role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thank you to @The Shift Exchange for helping me to work this one out. Turns out it was an issue with my filters, essentially I was applying a filter based on a role name - unfortunately when testing my editing functionality i had inadvertently edited the name of my admin role - User error!!!

Thanks again for all your help, maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try removing all the excess routes and work backwards - rebuild the routes one by one?